# GraphData does not work in the cloud

Tags: bugs, graphs-and-networks, curated-data, wolfram-cloud

**Bug introduced in 12.1 cloud**

---

Currently, [`GraphData`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GraphData.html)
 does not seem to work in the cloud.

For example, `GraphData["TutteGraph"]`, `GraphData["PetersenGraph"]` or `GraphData[3]` return unevaluated.

The same happens when using `CloudEvaluate`, e.g.

```
CloudEvaluate[GraphData["TutteGraph"], Hold]
(* Hold[GraphData["TutteGraph"]] *)
```

Is there a way to get a result from `GraphData` in the cloud?

---

The current cloud version is:

```
In[]:= $Version
Out[]= 12.1.0 for Linux x86 (64-bit) (March 4, 2020)
```

---

**Update**:

Response from Wolfram Technical Support:

It does appear that the `GraphData["TutteGraph"]` is not evaluating in Wolfram Cloud. I have forwarded an issue report to our developers with the information you provided.

Comment: I can confirm - it doesn't work for me at the moment. Seems to be a problem with Wolfram Cloud.

Comment: Even graphs from the documentation page don't work, e.g. "PappusGraph". Please report this to Wolfram, hopefully they'll fix it soon.

Comment: Looks like it’s maintenance. https://twitter.com/wolframops/status/1247915238592217089?s=21

Comment: Let us know if I was wrong and the problem persists.